# Code Build in JDK 1.5 but runtime uses 1.8, any performance issues?

Tags: java, java-8, java-5

Our project has legacy frameworks that needed 1.5 as a compulsory JDK version to build. But in runtime, we use JDK 1.8. Will there be any performance impact, as we are creating the binaries using JDK 1.5?

Comment: try it and see.

Answer (score 3):

> Will there be any performance impact, as we are creating the binaries
> using JDK 1.5?

You can rest assured that the performance of an application compiled using JDK 1.5 will run with better performance on JRE 1.8. Many things get improved with a higher version of Java and certainly, your application will benefit from the improved JVM.

Nevertheless, I strongly recommend you perform the PT (Performance Test) before production rollout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as expected higher version of JDK performed better